# Could you share source code or package of Simple Forum section that uses Auth of Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have existed project in Laravel 5.8 with Auth builded, If you have ready source code or package of Simple Forum section, please share, because I really don't have time to make it by my own. I just needed functions as make discussion, show number of replies, like so.

Comment: That's not how SO works.  Pls have a look at [the help centre guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a description of what questions are appropriate.  A simple search turns up [many](https://github.com/laracasts/Lets-Build-a-Forum-in-Laravel), [many](https://packagist.org/packages/riari/laravel-forum), [many](https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter), [many](https://medium.com/employbl/build-an-online-forum-with-laravel-analyzing-the-application-part-3-9317a0f893b4) resources. [There's even a full course on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel).

Comment: @Don'tPanic I understand, just asking maybe someone already have good resource and suggestion, course in Laravel is too big